# CoreData+MagicalRecord.h file not found

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I got stuck into pretty simple looking error but I am not able to solve it.

I am trying to add MagicalRecord into my project with the help of [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/56879/magicalrecord-tutorial-ios) tutorial, but, after adding `#import "CoreData+MagicalRecord.h"` in prefix.pch I am getting `CoreData+MagicalRecords.h file not found error`.

I also tried `#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecord.h>` this but same error.

What can be the issue.

UPDATE:

Adding my prefix file code here.

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "Constants.h"
    #define MR_SHORTHAND
    #import "CoreData+MagicalRecord.h"
#endif
```

Comment: Did you actually added Magical Records files to your project ?

Comment: Have you tried just `#import "MagicalRecord.h"` things changed in `2.2`, `2.3` so the tutorial might be out of date.

Comment: Yes, I have added them. On clicking "Revel in finder", it takes me to correct place

Comment: @sbarow, after adding #import "MagicalRecord.h" it gives me error in MagicalRecord.h file saying #import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecordInternal.h> not found

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/Docs/Installing-MagicalRecord.md

Comment: Have you resolved this? Can you show the whole content of the prefix.pch file?

Comment: @yoninja .. No, I couldn't resolved it. Currently as workaround I am using the old MagicalRecord.h

Comment: Can show the content of the prefix.pch file?

Comment: @yoninja .. i have added that as an update part in my question.

Comment: @JiteshW It should be `#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecord.h>`. Can you give a try with the current master branch (by using `pod 'MagicalRecord', :git => 'https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord'`)? Please update me if the issue is now solved or if it's still a problem.

Comment: @Cœur, Can't test. No longer working on that project.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be directly related to the original question's problem, but could come in handy.

If you are using Magical Record 2.3 beta 6 or later, it seems from the issues that there was a problem with manual importing that never got sorted out. See https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/1019 (thought the referenced issue claims to have fixed it, I beg to differ)

I was able to get my manual version to build and run by converting my imports from the format `#import <MagicalRecord/filename.h>` to `#import "filename.h"`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem before. This sounds ridiculous but move `#import <CoreData+MagicalRecord.h>` above `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`. Note the use of `<>` instead of `""` if you are using pods.

**Edit**
Please take note that this is an old answer. It worked for me before when I posted it. It may not work anymore... I have not used MagicalRecord for quite some time now.

Comment: Ok, will try your solution and let you know. Thanks :)

Comment: Obsolete answer: `CoreData+MagicalRecord.h` doesn't exist anymore in MagicalRecord.